# Reference a list property in a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I have models.

```
namespace GbngWebClient.Models
{
    public class UserProfileMulti25
    {
        public int SelectionId { get; set; }
        public int ProfileCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool SelectedSwitch { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GbngWebClient.Models
{
    public class UserProfileForMaintVM
    {
    public UserProfileSingleVM UserProfileSingleVM { get; set; }
    public List<UserProfileMulti25> UserProfileMultiList25 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to load a property which is a list in the UserProfileForMaintVM model.

I'm getting "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I do the add.

```
// Instantiate a new UserProfileForMaintVM.
UserProfileForMaintVM userProfileForMaintVM = new UserProfileForMaintVM();

UserProfileMulti25 userProfileMulti25 = new UserProfileMulti25
{
   SelectionId = hold.SelectionId,
   ProfileCategoryId = hold.ProfileCategoryId,
   Description = hold.Description,
   SelectedSwitch = hold.SelectedSwitch
};

// Add the multi list to the model's multi list.
userProfileForMaintVM.UserProfileMultiList25.Add(userProfileMulti25);
```

So I think I need to instantiate the UserProfileMultiList25 list in the UserProfileForMaintVM model. 
I'm am trying to instantiate the UserProfileMultiList25 list in the UserProfileForMaintVM model but none of these work.

How do I do this?

```
 // This one I get: userProfileForMaintVM is a variable but  used like a type.
 userProfileForMaintVM.UserProfileMultiList25 a = new userProfileForMaintVM.UserProfileMultiList25();

 // This one I get: The type name UserProfileMultiList25 does not exist in the type UserProfileForMaintVM.
 UserProfileForMaintVM.UserProfileMultiList25 b = new UserProfileForMaintVM.UserProfileMultiList25();

 // This one I get: The type name List<> does not exist in the type UserProfileForMaintVM.
 UserProfileForMaintVM.List<UserProfileMulti25> c = new UserProfileForMaintVM.List<UserProfileMulti25>();
```

---

In my view, I can reference the UserProfileSingleVM property just fine.

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.UserProfileForMaintVM

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.WhoIAmDescr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct with instantiating the list first. You could **add a constructor** within the class and create the list there. In this way, everytime `UserProfileForMaintVM` is instantiated, it will automatically create a List.

```
public class UserProfileForMaintVM
{
   // add this to your model
   public UserProfileForMaintVM(){
      this.UserProfileMultiList25 = new List<UserProfileMulti25>();
   }

   public UserProfileSingleVM UserProfileSingleVM {get;set;}
   public List<UserProfileMulti25> UserProfileMultiList25{get;set;}
}
```